# How to ues Conjugate Gradients (CG) to computes Inverse-Hessian vector products(IHVP)?

Tags: influence-function

I do not understand the conjugate gradients(CG) in computing the Inverse-Hessian vector products(IHVP) of this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.04730, does someone know about the calculation process of Using CG for IHVP? Or Can you give me some hints?

Comment: I think you need to edit to say what you understand already so people do not waste time explaining those steps to you.